# Why am I getting a python list index error in this code?

Tags: python, list, error-handling

The question is:
You are given a list. Print the sum of the list numbers. If the list is empty then 0 gets printed. Also, the element 7 and the element next to it won't contribute to the sum.

```
def realSum(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        if arr[i] == 7:
            del arr[i:i+2]
    return sum(arr)
```

Why is this code giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/welcome/PycharmProjects/ko/ko.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(realSum(arr))
  File "C:/Users/welcome/PycharmProjects/ko/ko.py", line 11, in realSum
    if arr[i] == 7:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This code works when using a while loop but doesn't work when using for loop.
Why is that so?

Comment: Note that `range(len(arr)-1)` is executed once before the loop starts. That isn't "checked" each iteration.

Comment: Don’t modify the list you’re iterating over, you’ll have all sorts of side effects.

Comment: Hang on, you're just trying to get the sum of a list?

Comment: @Carcigenicate  I am really sorry but can you please elaborate more?

Comment: As in, you just want the total of all the elements added up in the list? (The sum)

Comment: @Treatybreaker You are given a list. Print the sum of the list numbers. If the list is empty then 0 gets printed. Also, the element 7 and the element next to it won't contribute to the sum.

Comment: Every time you call `del`, the list gets shorter, but you're still iterating until `i` is the original length of `arr`. That will be out of bounds if you remove any elements.

Comment: @SoumikPaul I would totally agree with deceze's comment. You are deleting from the list you are iterating over, and at some point, you will end up calling an index of list that you already deleted, hence out of range.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh yeah right! I am so stupid I didn't notice this silly mistake!

Comment: You would be better off just using a list comprehension, having it exclude any `7`s while iterating, then sum the new list that the comprehension produces. That would make much more sense.

Comment: @Ehsan Yeah thanks. But how do i edit the code such that I get my answer?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Can you please write that out in a code format?

Comment: I'm hesitant to give any code as this seems like homework; and even if it's not, just giving code is a poor way to learn. If you've never used a list comprehension before, look them up. Seriously. They are one of the most fundamental constructs in Python. Trying to write Python without using list comprehensions will make your life harder than it needs to be, and they're the most idiomatic way to solve this particular problem.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes thanks, now I have solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(len(arr)-1)` is calculated before the loop starts to iterate. Now, lets take the following input:

```
arr = [7, 7, 7]
```

So your loop will iterate over the following `i`s - 0,1:

- In the first iteration, where `i=0`, the first 2 elements of `arr` will be deleted so there will be only one element in `arr`
- In the second iteration, where `i=1`, `arr[i]` will raise an `IndexError` exception because you're trying to access the second element of list of size 1.

This is a *classical* example of why it is a bad practice to mutate a list which you're iteration over.

Comment: Thank you! I really am so silly, dulling over such a silly mistake!